# Casting size_t during malloc to initialize char* array in c

Tags: c, casting, malloc, c-strings, size-t

I am reviewing some of my old code and the way I used to initialize malloc() for c strings seemingly works but on closer inspection I am concerned of possible buffer overflow.

My current style is to get the size_t of a char and multiple that by the value I want. For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *string = malloc(sizeof(char) * PATH_MAX + 1);
    /* do stuff */
    free(string);
    return somevalue;
 }
```

However My older code I just cast the value of size_t to the value i wanted such as instead of using

```
    char *string = malloc(sizeof(char) * PATH_MAX + 1);
```

I used

```
    char *string = malloc((size_t)PATH_MAX + 1);
```

Since I am allocating a character array malloc will take the value of the data type and use that as the proper byte size making the two previous statements analogous or did I create an accidental chance of a buffer overflow with the given assumption that the string to be put into "string" is less than the size of PATH_MAX.

Comment: `malloc(PATH_MAX+1)` is simplest

Comment: Instead of dynamically allocating a few KB, just declare `char string[ PATH_MAX + 1 ];` ( @M.M - that's even simpler ;-) ) On the vast majority of today's systems, a few KB of data fits easily on the stack.  On multithreaded programs using the stack instead of the heap has the added benefit of totally avoiding heap contention - twice.  You should know already if you're programming for a platform where a few KB of data is too big for your stack.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(char)` is rarely informative.  By definition it is always 1 and of type `size_t`.

```
// Both attempt to allocate the same amount.
char *string1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * PATH_MAX + 1);
char *string2 = malloc((size_t)PATH_MAX + 1);
```

The following is *slightly* different.  Although simpler, depending on the type of `PATH_MAX`, pedantically, `PATH_MAX + 1` may overflow.

```
char *string3 = malloc(PATH_MAX + 1);
```

Better is

```
char *string4 = malloc(PATH_MAX + 1u);
```

Pedantically this should be

```
char *string5 = malloc(PATH_MAX + (size_t)1); // or like string2 above
```

Alternatively, use the `sizeof_referenced_variable * element_count` idiom and avoid type issues.

```
string6 = malloc(sizeof *string6 * (PATH_MAX + 1u));
```

---

Using `sizeof_this * N` has an advantage vs. `N * sizeof_this` when `N` is a formula.

```
int rows, columns;
...
                                 v------v----- size_t multiplication                        
matrix1 = malloc(sizeof *matrix1 * rows * columns);
                      v----------- int multiplication (overflow possible)                  
                      |         v- size_t multiplication                        
matrix2 = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof *matrix2);
```

Of course if the product overflows `size_t` math, code is [SOL](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shit_out_of_luck).

Answer (score 0):

> My current style is to get the `size_t` of a char and multiple that by the value I want.

C standard guarantees that `sizeof(char)` evaluates to `1` for all standard-compliant compilers, so multiplication is entirely unnecessary.

Your old and your new expressions should translate to the same code.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to malloc is the number of bytes for which you want to allocate memory. Since sizeof(char) is 1 byte as per C standard, both method will allocate same amount of memory.